# How to avoid fs::directory_iterator exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11, std-filesystem, filesystemexception

I'm using the following loop to extract names of files and directories from a root path.

```
for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(dirToList, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied, ec)) {
.
Doing some work
.
}
```

I've use `ec` in order to avoid the `exception` but i get the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: status: Too many levels of symbolic links [/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/proc/self/task/92639/fd/4/media/floppy]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The above error seems to be due to symbolic link so i used the following to avoid it.

```
                if(fs::is_symlink(entry, ec)){
                    std::cerr << "Avoiding symlink!" << std::endl;
                    continue;
                }
```

still same exception.

1. How to resolve the above issue.
2. How to avoid all exceptions related to std::filesystem::experimental altogether. I can go with return error approach as I do not want to handle `exceptions`.

Comment: Try `.increment(ec)` instead of `++` (meaning you can no longer use ranged-for).

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but is your compiler outdated? I believe they all stopped using `experimental::` for the filesystem stuff.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is old. I'm on ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.4.0. I need to support some old Linux distribution therefor stuck with legacy compilers

Comment: Kindly elaborate it a little, i didn't get this "Try .increment(ec) instead of ++" You means to say that i should use something like this. i.e
auto it = fs::directory_iterator(path); for (auto i = fs::begin(it); fs::begin(i) != fs::end(it); ) { }

Comment: The ranged-for (`for (... : ...)`) internally uses `++` to increment the iterator, and here `++` can throw. Rewrite the loop to use the old-school syntax (`for (...; ...; ...)` or `while`), and instead of using `++it` to increment the iterator, use `it.increment(ec)` and check the error code.